# SAS libname to odbc only show one row?

Tags: odbc, sas

For example I have in MySql database a table named "courses":

"course_code" "course_title"
"C001"  "Basic Telecommunications"
"C002"  "Structured Query Language"
"C003"  "Local Area Networks"
"C004"  "Database Design"
"C005"  "Artificial Intelligence"
"C006"  "Computer Aided Design"

then in SAS I did this:
libname samples odbc dsn=mydsn (Assuming mydsn connects to MySql);

Now in the explorer I will have a dataset "courses" in samples library.
However, when I double click to open the dataset it only shows ONE row???

I am using SAS 9.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a proc print instead?

```
proc print data=samples.courses ;
run ;
```